# Constucing a query in mysql/php when records are altered

Tags: mysql

I am using php and mysqli. I have a table which has pupil_id and pupil_condition and primary_key.

The pupil_conditions are displayed as a series of about 8 check boxes

For a pupil with say id 10 I might have three records likes this:

```
p_id, p_c, pk
10,   5,   6
10,   3,   7
10,   7,   8
```

Now the user changes the selection of pupil_condition boxes.

At the moment I am deleting all the existing records for this pupil, and inserting the news ones. This works, but seems clumsy.

I have thought about maybe this:

```
if (record exists)
 {skip}
elseif (record exists but not in new selection)
 {delete}
elseif (record doesn't exisit)
 {insert}
```

is there some query type that I don't know about that would help with this?

Comment: UPDATE 'table' WHERE...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:
`DELETE FROM table WHERE p_id=10 AND p_c NOT IN [ids_of_the_checked_conditions]`

this has to delete all rows with `p_id=10` and conditions (condition ids) that are no more checked for this pupil.

and `INSERT` statement after the delete to insert all of the checked ones. (You can create unique index on both `p_id` and `p_c` so no repeating rows will occur)

Comment: thanks - really works well for the delete query. Can't see how to avoid duplicate records for the insert - think that's where  MaggsWeb's answer might come in???